# Correct format of my input array

Tags: java

For my code the user has to input the elements of the array. I am trying to figure out how to format it so the user can input the elements of the array side by side.
Any suggestions?

For example:
my first array contains from the user = `[34, 56,98]`

my second array contains from the user = `[100,80,78]`

I would like the input to look like this after the user as input the elements. I must use two arrays! Thank you!

```
34  100

56  80

98  78
```

This is how I am currently inputting the numbers in my array.

```
      int userNumber = kbd.nextInt();//user decides how big array will be 
      int [] firstArray = new int[userNumber];

      for(int i =0; i< firstArray.length; i++){
      firstArray[i]= kbd.nextInt(); 


     }
```

Comment: Showing what you've written so far would be a good start. We're not here to do your homework for you.

Comment: This sounds to me like a homework question

Comment: i have added an edit with my current attempt

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `string.split(' ');`
This will use a space between entries as the delimiter and break them up. You can then use

```
int temp =  Integer.parseint(string [index])

intArr [index] = temp;
```

Comment: So I change the type for my arrays to string and then just convert them to integer? Does this mean I have to use just one array?

Comment: Just receive the input as a string and then try using a for loop to parse the input to integers and store them in their appropriate arrays